# Proper usage of commas when listing items in a sentence

Tags: meaning

In the gas company flyer, it says "We will not disconnect gas service for non-payment if you can prove that a permanent resident of your home is 62 or older, handicapped or that being without gas service would be especially dangerous to someone living in the home."

Does that mean a resident 62 or older and handicapped, or does it mean 62 or older or handicapped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conjunction used for the **last** item in a list should be applied to the **whole list,** where there is any chance of ambiguity. This is the standard rule for disambiguation.

It is **slightly** complicated in this example because one of the list items also uses *or,* but the meaning can be worked out by separating the list:

> - 62 or older
> - handicapped
> - in danger

The conjunction *or* is then applied to the whole list:

> 62 or older
>   or handicapped
>   or in danger

Any one of those conditions applying will be sufficient to stop the company disconnecting the gas.